# sonata_type_collection doesn't call the setCollection() method in my entity

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have 2 entities. User and Address. User has many addresses. I want to implement the sonata_type_collection field in my user create form.

I've set the reference_by to false, created the appropriate methods in my User entity.
it's my formtype in the UserAdminClass

```
        ->add('addresses', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                // Prevents the "Delete" option from being displayed
                'type_options' => array('delete' => false, 'by_reference' => false)
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'sortable',
            ))
```

and this is my methods in the User entity:

```
    public function setAddresses($addresses)
    {
    $this->addresses->clear();

    foreach ($addresses as $address) {
        $this->addAddress($address);
    }
}

public function getAddresses()
{
    return $this->addresses;
}

/**
 * Add addresses
 * вызывается при нажатии на кнопку "добавить новый" в сонате на коллекции
 * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Address $addresses
 * @return User
 */
public function addAddress(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Address $addresses)
{
    $addresses->setUser($this);
    $this->addresses[] = $addresses;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove addresses
 *
 * @param \Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Address $addresses
 */
public function removeAddress(\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Address $addresses)
{
    $this->addresses->removeElement($addresses);

}
```

But when i submit my form it makes dublicates of the existent linked addresses. I can't delete addresses and can't add new when I have no addresses exist.

I figured out, that on the form submission the method setAddresses have to be called, but it haven't, so my addresses collections doesn't clear every time and it makes dublicates. (I hope i understood it right).

I use symfony 2.5 and latest sonata. 
I've read all the google and stackoverflow, but there's same issues, posted in 2012.